# How to wire lamp bulb holder

Tags: wiring

[image]I bought a brass lamp holder fitting online, but can't figure out how to wire it up. I'd be so grateful for any help, it's for my late granddad's old lamp and I'd love to see it working again.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post a picture of the top side.

Comment: Just added, thanks Marti

Comment: State your location, tension (230v or 110v) and the colors of the wires

Answer (score 2):

The hot (black) wire is connected to the screw on the bottom connected to the springy tab, and the neutral (white) wire is connected to the screw with the threaded metal.  The ground (green) wire is connected to the metal chassis of the lamp itself.  Older lamps probably don't have a screw for ground.  You can make one with a tap or self tapping screw.

Comment: Thanks so much Andrew, that's great

Comment: The OP is probably somewhere in Europe where the color code is different (the socket is marked for an E27 base, not E26). The color are hard to see in the photo but I doubt they are black white and green.

Comment: @DoxyLover   My eyes see black, brown, and a light yellow.  I do not think old or new UK wire colours used black and brown together.  They used one or the other with different colours.

Comment: Looks like brown, yellow, and blue or black to me.

Comment: This design confuses me slightly.  Normally the wires do not connect inside the socket area, and I don't see contacts outside the ceramic. I presume one is supposed to dismount the socket itself from the ceramic by removing the two recessed screws and there will be contact points on its back; that would resemble the socket housings I'm used to...